# Dynamically adding rows to tableview

Tags: c++, qt

I want to have a table view in Qt. It has four column and "n" rows at the start in table view. How can I dynamically add rows?

Answer (score 8):

there is a huge set of functions for that ,

```
void    appendColumn ( const QList<QStandardItem *> & items )
void    appendRow ( const QList<QStandardItem *> & items )
void    appendRow ( QStandardItem * item )
void    insertColumn ( int column, const QList<QStandardItem *> & items )
bool    insertColumn ( int column, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex() )
void    insertRow ( int row, const QList<QStandardItem *> & items )
bool    insertRow ( int row, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex() )
void    insertRow ( int row, QStandardItem * item )
```

look in [qt docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstandarditemmodel.html) for their description

UPD:

```
QStandardItemModel m(3,3);
QList<QStandardItem*> newRow;
for (int i=0;i<m.colCount();i++)
{
    QStandardItem* itm = new QStandardItem(QString("data for col %1").arg(i));
    newRow.append(itm);
}
m.append(newRow);
```

haven't test it but it should work

Comment: Sir can you please give an example or link to example because i am new to it i dont understand the documentation only i need some example thanks

Comment: @sajid, make sure to take a look at all the Qt examples, there are plenty that should illustrate how to use it: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/all-examples.html